# How to use UITableview data source and delegates with SwiftBond?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftbond

I am using [SwiftBond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond) to bind tableview. I want to have index list in my tableview but i have no idea of how to implement it.

I want to use few more data source methods of tableview but i am not having exact idea of the correct way to do it.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by implementing `BNDTableViewProxyDataSource`.

And I need to pass instance of BNDTableViewProxyDataSource when i bind tableview using `bindTo` method.

Comment: @"Alap Anerao" do you know how to do this using SwiftBond v5? `BNDTableViewProxyDataSource` is gone in v5. The closest I got is using `tableView.bnd_dataSource.forwardTo = self` to redirect the data source back to my view controller, but then I also need to implement the required methods of `UITableViewDataSource` in my view controller and I'm stuck there